# setcookie and header in auto login

Tags: php, cookies, authentication

I want to auto login after user's registration. I have the same script for login and it doesn't work after registration. What could be wrong? It's a bit old script, but I really want to make it work again.
http://pastie.org/private/ibfebmgzfo6ovug0pnjudg

Comment: Define not working (page doesn't display, page displays but nothing happens, error in console, etc.)...

Answer (score 0):

I'd strongly recommend not using the script or change it drasticly. Using MD5 to hash a password is obsolete and the password is passed via a `POST-request` in plain text to this page. Besides it's vulnerable for SQL-injection. Not secure at all.

Comment: But I don't have much time to change it drasticly.

Comment: Then you'd better look for a different script

Comment: Again: "But I don't have much time"...This script worked and doesn't work for now, so I only want to fix it for a while.

Comment: change `SetCookie` to `setcookie` and try again

Comment: try changing `$hash = md5($REMOTE_ADDR.$date.$password);` to `$hash = md5($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].$date.$password);` and you never defined `$date`, so define that.

Comment: nothing. If I try test cookie on the beginning of the script, the cookie isn't created.